# Como simplificar o código Hexadecimal #ff6a00

Tags: html, css, layout

Preciso simplicar este código hexadecimal #ff6a00, exite alguma regra ?
tem alguma formula ?

Comment: Defina *simplificar*.

Comment: Um numeracao menor para a mesma cor!

Comment: para a tag a cima estou testando isso #f60 ou # f6a0

Comment: `#f6a0` é um formato inválido para definição de cor, ou 8 bits por cor (`#RRGGBB`) ou 4 (`#RGB`). Talvez seja interpretado como (`#RGBA`), o que tornaria a cor transparente (alfa = 0)

Comment: QUal é a utilidade de ter um código ligeiramente menor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma de simplificar seria substituir o código hexadecimal da cor pelo nome da mesma, nessa [tabela](http://www.flextool.com.br/tabela_cores.html) tem os nomes e códigos hexadecimais de cada cor.

Exemplo: background-color: #ADFF2F tem o mesmo efeito que background-color: GreenYellow

Ai é só procurar a cor mais próxima do código hexadecimal citado e substituir pelo nome da cor em questão.

Comment: Mas **`GreenYellow`** tem mais caracteres que **`#ADFF2F`**

Comment: Pensei que quando ele fala em simplificar ele estivesse se referindo à sintaxe visando facilitar o uso de uma cor e não com relação à quantidade de caracteres.

Comment: É que ele explica isso nos comentários.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**: Não há maneira de simplificar.

**Versão longa**:

- Em *notação hexadecimal longa* isso não é possível, já que é o formato original utilizado na pergunta (`#RRGGBB`).
- Em *notação hexadecimal curta* (`#RGB`) isso não é possível, já que é o formato do componente verde (`#6a`) não pode ser simplificado sem perda de resolução da cor. Versões próximas: `#f60` ou `#f70`.
- Em *LESS* você pode definir um alias curto para a cor.

Exemplo LESS:

```
@o: #ff6a00; 
#title { color: @o; }
```

Ainda assim, a versão compilada apresentará o conteúdo completo:

```
#title { color: #ff6a00; }
```